# Is there such a thing as caching too much in MonoBehaviour Scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Scripts tend up to be filled to the brim with cached component references such as this:

```
using Scripts.Combat;
using Scripts.Core;
using Scripts.Movement;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Scripts.Control
{
    public class AIController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float chaseRadius = 5f;
        [SerializeField] float suspicionTime = 3f;

        GameObject _player;
        Fighter _fighter;
        Health _health;
        Mover _mover;
        ActionScheduler _actionScheduler;

        Vector3 _guardPosition;
        float _timeSinceLastSawPlayer = Mathf.Infinity;

        void Start()
        {
            AssignVariables();
        }

        void AssignVariables()
        {
            _player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
            _fighter = GetComponent<Fighter>();
            _health = GetComponent<Health>();
            _mover = GetComponent<Mover>();
            _actionScheduler = GetComponent<ActionScheduler>();
            
            _guardPosition = transform.position;
        }
```

To me this just feels cluttered and noisy. Is this really the most efficient way of going about the issue of not having GetComponent<>() calls in your Update() methods?

Comment: No. That’s normal. The only thing to ask yourself is is this script doing too much should I have less in it and more specific scripts that then become reusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as going "the standard way" no - there is no other "better" way or more performant

If you can decrease the performance of your code a bit for caching, you can create dependency injection. [Here](https://www.effectiveunity.com/unity/01-dependency-injection-with-unity-part-1/) author goes into detail on how this could work, and what are the drawbacks of such a system.

Example on how dependency injection might work.

```
//pseudo-code you would put into Awake or Start or wrap in another class
var fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach(var field in fields)
{
    if(typeof(MonoBehaviour).IsAsignableFrom(field.FieldType))
    {
        //Add better handling for different types, or array of components
        field.SetValue(this, GetComponent(field.FieldType));
    }
}
```

You can go the other way around and get rid of Components via new approach that is not using MonoBehaviour and Components at all is the [Entity Component System](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/entity-component-system). But this is a complete shift in how you would program your game.

Comment: ECS blew my mind. If anyone else finds this post, please look into ECS asap.

Comment: Please keep in mind that as of 2020 this is still NOT production-ready, but I would say pretty usable at this point

Comment: Not only that, the lack of documentation will probably make it difficult for most to pick up at the moment anyway. but I definitely think that anyone who are interested in making games with Unity long term should start reading up now and fiddle around with it a bit here and there until it becomes fully production ready. Performance gains of up to a 100 times is pretty insane..